AssertionError: Out of bounds observation when using action mask in Petting zoo env
I have a custom Petting Zoo parallel env, which worked fine until I added some action masks.
I follow the action_masking tutorial and try to implement action masking in this way (in a different class from the Env) :
def compute_action_mask(self) -> np.array:
        """Return the action mask"""
        current_state = self.get_current_state()
        if current_state == "g":
            if self.consecutive_durations["g"] < self.env.min_green_time:
                action_mask = np.array([1, 0, 0], dtype=np.int8)
            else:
                action_mask = np.array([1, 1, 0], dtype=np.int8)
        elif current_state == "y":
            if self.consecutive_durations["y"] < self.env.yellow_time:
                action_mask = np.array([0, 1, 0], dtype=np.int8)
            elif self.consecutive_durations["y"] == self.env.yellow_time:
                action_mask = np.array([0, 0, 1], dtype=np.int8)
        else:
            if self.consecutive_durations["r"] >= self.env.max_red_time:
                action_mask = np.array([1, 0, 0], dtype=np.int8)
            else:
                action_mask = np.array([1, 0, 1], dtype=np.int8)
        return action_mask

And now my observations dict follows the structure (in the Env class):
def _compute_observations(self) -> dict:
        """ Compute and return the observations
        Returns:
            observations (dict): dict of the form {id_agent: {'observation' : [], 'action_mask' : []}}
        """
        observations = {}
        for id_agent, agent in self.dict_feux.items():
            observations[id_agent] = {
                "observation" : agent.compute_observation(), 
                "action_mask" : agent.compute_action_mask()
            }
        return observations

But when I tested this env (firstly converted into aec env) with the api_test method of petting zoo (because it seems that the parallel_api_test does not look at action masks), I have the following error :
AssertionError: Out of bounds observation: {'observation': array([ 0. , 13.9], dtype=float32), 'action_mask': array([1, 0, 1], dtype=int8)}
My current observation space:
def observation_space(self) -> spaces.Box:
        """Return the observation space."""
        return spaces.Box(
            low=0, 
            high=100,
            shape=(2,), 
            dtype=np.float32
        )

If I understand this error, I should change my observation space. But how to change it to match the add of the action masking ?
